# how I can convert an object to string?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using jQuery and the console returns me:

```
Data Loaded: [object Object]
```

The **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Button click event

    $("#ajaxForm").submit(function(e){
        // disable the form submit
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $( this ),
    term = $form.find( 'input[name="id"]' ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( 'update' );


    /* Send the data using ajax */
    var posting =
        $.ajax({
            url: url
        });

    $.post(url, { id: term } ).done(function(data) {
        console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);
        $("#result").empty().append(data);      
    });
});
```

how I can convert the result of 'json' in a "string". thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? jQuery goes out of its way to do the conversion JSON => object for you specifically because that's what you want almost all of the time. But in any case, if for some reason you really want a string, use the `dataType: 'text'` option of `$.post` to prevent this.

Comment: I believe it's for logging purposes, he wants the content of the JSON rather than the mere statement that it's an Object.

Comment: right, it's for logging purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
JSON.stringify(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert JSON Object to String, use the below code.

```
JSON.stringify(data);
```

"data" is your JSON object.

To convert back string into JSON Object, use the below code.

```
JSON.parse(String);
```

Comment: JSON.parse(String); "String" that would be in this case.

Comment: You can use "stringify" to convert an object to string, as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post(url, returnFunction(data){...}, 'text');
```

will ensure that `data` is in text format, but if you instead do the following:

```
$.post(url, returnFunction(data){...}, 'json');
```

Then jQuery will automatically ensure `data` is a JSON object.

Note, jQuery will try to intelligently guess what the data is and pass back the correct object, putting 'text' or 'json' just makes this explicit.

Answer (score 0):

which returns json is incorrect. By clicking "submit" the form and hopes to return a JSON.
form is returned.

the script is correct?

```
$("#ajaxForm").submit(function(e){
    // disable the form submit
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

in this case the events do not work, but the submit button, does not work.

The **form.html**.

```
< form action = "update" method = "post" id = "ajaxForm" >
        < fieldset class = "success" >
        < legend > The fields marked with * . < /legend>
        < div >
        < label for = "destination" class = "block" >
        host:
        < span class = "mandatory_asterisk" > * < /span>
        < /label>
        < select id = "destination" class = "select" name = "destination" >
        < option value = "element1" > element1 < /option>
        < option value = "element2" > element2 < /option>
        < /select>
        < /div>
        < div >
        < span class = "infoTrigger" > Update a page of the search < /span>
        < label for = "id" class = "block" >
        page
you want to index:
        < /label>
        < input type = "text" class = "text" id = "page" name = "page"
        value = "" / >
        < /div>
        < div >
        < span class = "infoTrigger" > Update a certain id of the host < /span>
        < label for = "id" class = "block" >
        id
on the host (e.g. element1 - id - post - json):
        < /label>
        < input type = "text" class = "text" id = "id" name = "id"
        value = "" / >
        < /div>
        < !-- < input id = "operation" type = "submit" / > -- >
        < input type = "submit" value = "update" name = "update" id = "operation" / >
        < /fieldset>
        < div id = "anotherSection" >
        < fieldset >
        < legend > Response from jQuery Ajax Request < /legend>
        < div id = "result" > < /div>
        < /fieldset>
        < /div>
        < /form>
```